# Existence of primitive totally real number fields

Tags: nt.number-theory

For any positive integer n, is there always a primitive totally real number field of degree n over $\mathbb Q$?  I am new to this field. Please forgive me for asking such an elementary question.

Comment: What does "primitive" mean in this context? To make totally real fields of any degree you like, start with a cyclotomic field, intersect it with the reals, and then use Galois theory to cook up subfields. 

Comment: It means that it is the splitting field of the minimal polynomial of a primitive element. Thanks for your answer.